# missing closing parenthesis

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am porting this stored procedure over from mssql to mysql and am getting an error saying that I am missing closing parenthesis which I cannot seem to find why.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_oids (IN sys_info VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT oids.id, oids.attribute, oids.description_oid, oids.mib_name, oids.classifier  
    FROM oids
    INNER JOIN mib_mappings 
        ON mib_mappings.name = oids.mib_name
    WHERE ((sys_info LIKE '%' + mib_mappings.model + '%' AND sys_info LIKE '%' + mib_mappings.vendor + '%') OR mib_mappings.model = 'ALL')
        AND oids.nodeType = 'CHILD' AND oids.descriptionOID is not null
    GROUP BY oids.id, oids.attribute, oids.description_oid, oids.mib_name, o.classifier
END
```

Comment: @Matt This is everything already, also I am guessing I need a semicolon at the end of GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check with it, I think the problem is with like and the missing semicolon at the end of group by:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_oids (IN sys_info VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT oids.id, 
    oids.attribute, 
    oids.description_oid, 
    oids.mib_name, 
    oids.classifier  
FROM oids
INNER JOIN mib_mappings ON mib_mappings.name = oids.mib_name
WHERE ((sys_info LIKE CONCAT('%',mib_mappings.model,'%') 
    AND sys_info LIKE CONCAT('%',mib_mappings.vendor,'%') 
    OR mib_mappings.model = 'ALL')
    AND oids.nodeType = 'CHILD' 
    AND oids.descriptionOID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY oids.id, oids.attribute, oids.description_oid, oids.mib_name, o.classifier;
END
```

Comment: Can you please just provide table structure with create script so that I can check here properly.

Comment: that worked, sorry I did not see the CONCAT() function being changed

Comment: One thing I have noticed in where clause oids.descriptionOID is used in last and in selection and in group by oids.description_oid, if both should be same column name then we have to correct in where clause or if different then it's fine.